# Нахождение прямоугольных областей

Tags: python, opencv

Как реализовать нахождение прямоугольных областей на картинке и получение их высоты?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.